# Trigger Ajax request on settings page

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-5, octobercms, octobercms-plugins

I'm writing a plugin that have some fields defined in backend settings.

One of that field is a partial that contain a button, that trigger an **Ajax** request thanks to the data-attribute API.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-request="onReset">
    My button
</button>
```

Where should I put the "`onReset()`" function ? I tried to put it in my Settings model, even tried to create a Settings controller (whereas not necessary to work with settings page), but I always get the following error :

```
Ajax handler 'onReset' was not found
```

I don't know what to do to be able to trigger that `onReset()` function, can somebody familiar with `Laravel / OctoberCMS` could point me the right direction ?

Thanks

Comment: You can do it inline (ugly) `<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-request="onReset" onclick="onReset()">` or create a seperate `.js` file that you include on the page (with a script tag) just before the `body` closing tag that registers an event handler when the document is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Settings are rendered by the `\System\Controllers\Settings` so whatever you write will be handled by `\System\Controllers\Settings` Controller Class,

> so we need to extend `\System\Controllers\Settings` and we can add dynamic 
>   method there,

inside your `plugin's boot method` you need to write this extension code

> **I am renaming your `onReset` handler to `onPrefixReset` in this example to avoid any other conflicts.**

```
public function boot() {

    \System\Controllers\Settings::extend(function($model) {

        $model->addDynamicMethod('onPrefixReset', function() {
            \Flash::success('You did it!');
            // OR
            //return ['some data data'];
        });
    });
}
```

**`onPrefixReset` : we are adding some `Prefix` here, so accidentally we are not overriding internal original methods.**

now inside your `_partial`

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-request="onPrefixReset">
    My button
</button>
```

so now this **`onPrefixReset`** ajax handler is defined in `\System\Controllers\Settings` as we did that dynamically ;) it will handle your request.

you can return any data from here  and it will be received at `back-end settings page`.

Comment: Is there any way to refresh the page after button click?

Comment: try this it will redirect page, so just use same url to make refresh page https://octobercms.com/docs/ajax/handlers#redirects-in-handlers

Answer (score -1):

In HTML forms if you have an onReset event, you can add your call inside there:

```
function updateForm()
{
    $.each($('form').find(":input"), function(){  
        $.uniform.update($(this));  
    });  
}

<form onReset="updateForm();">
```

In this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/shafayet1991/67bo7tce/) you can you can do your own ordering within a click event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input:reset").click(function() {       /click event
        this.form.reset();                    
        window.alert($("input:text").val());       
        return false;                          
    });
});
```

Comment: this is wrong context he is talking about October CMS server-side so it will not work